# Maclaurin polynomial for $\arcsin(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

How would I find the 3rd-order Maclaurin polynomial for $f(x) = \arcsin(x)$; with the interval $(0,\frac 3 4)$ to show it in terms of $x$?

Would you have to somehow manipulate it to $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$ ?

I've been stuck on this question for almost an hour, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \arcsin(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
or you could say: if $\arcsin(x) = a_1 x + a_3 x^3 + \ldots$ (think about why only odd powers should appear), then $x = \sin(\arcsin(x)) = \ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account what Robert Israel wrote, I suppose you properly arrived to something looking like
$$\arcsin(x) =x+\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^{5}\right)$$

Now, you want to express the same thing in terms of $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$. So, write that $\arcsin(x)$ is a polynomial of  $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$ with unknown coefficients (do not forget that a constant term should be required) and develop  again  $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$ as a Taylor series. Now, identify the coefficients. This will provide you a few linear equations, the unknowns being the coefficients. I let you building and solving these simple equations.